# Enable any disabled field in epicore

Tags: erp, epicorerp

How to enable any disabled field which are coming in the Grid  of any Form in Epicor10 through Customisation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If it is in the base form and it is disabled, it is probably disabled for a reason. Either the field is read only due to business logic or the user account lacks the access to edit it. Without a more specific question that is about the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the form in **Developer mode**
2. From the menu select **Tools
   Customization**
3. From the Customization Window choose **Tools >
       Wizards > Customization Wizards...**
4. Select the **Modify Extended Properties** option

This will lead you through a wizard to update properties like Enabled, and produce some custom code in the script window, you can then use this code where you need it (Button click event / form load event etc...).

As @Van-Amburg mentions, if they are disabled by Epicor there is probably a good reason.